# Why is this asking me for an Expression?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to open a report from a form, where the user fills in a start and end date.  My code is:

```
Docmd.OpenReport (rptAllSalesByDate, acViewReport, ,
"DateOfTransaction >= #" & me.txtStartDate & "# and DateOfTransaction =< #" & me.txtEndDate & "#",,,)
```

The above was broken into 2 lines for easier readability, but it's actually on one line.

It keeps saying it's expecting an expressing and highlighting the closing parenthesis.

Any ideas what I'm missing?  I know my Access is rusty.

Comment: Remove the parentheses.

Comment: Same error.  I think that's why I put them in, because it wasn't working without them either.

Comment: The commas at the end are not necessary and will cause that error.

Comment: That fixed it!  Thanks!

Comment: Is rptAllSalesByDate the actual report name or is this a VBA variable?

Answer (score 3):

Do not leaving trailing commas when no parameters are provided for those arguments. This will trigger the indicated error. So will parentheses when not executing a function.

Consider:

```
Docmd.OpenReport "rptAllSalesByDate", acViewReport, , 
"DateOfTransaction BETWEEN #" & Me.txtStartDate & "# AND #" & Me.txtEndDate & "#"
```